# googleearthengine - Code to calculate EVI having rendering issues

Tags: google-earth-engine, google, evi

Below is the link of my code to calculate EVI in Google Earth engine. It is not giving/rendering color according to the color palette! Please help me in this regard.
https://code.earthengine.google.com/995504963211f6c4d300ac364dc6697c

```js
function maskS2clouds(image) {

  var qa = image.select('QA60');


  var cloudBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(10).int();
  var cirrusBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(11).int();


  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0).and(
             qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

var composite = s2.filterDate('2018-03-01', '2018-03-15')
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
                  .filterBounds(ft)
                  .map(maskS2clouds)
                  //.multiply(100)
                  .median();



Map.setCenter(87.32,22.40, 6);
Map.addLayer(composite, {bands: ['B6', 'B4', 'B3'], min: 0, max: 0.3},'fcc');


var landcover_roi = composite.clip(ft);
var evi =landcover_roi.expression(
    '2.5 * ((NIR-RED) / (NIR +6 * RED -7.5* BLUE))', {
      'NIR':landcover_roi.select('B8'),
      'RED':landcover_roi.select('B4'),
      'BLUE':landcover_roi.select('B2')
    });
Map.addLayer(ft, {}, 'From Fusion Table');

var EVI=evi.multiply(100).uint8()
var meanDictionary = EVI.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry: ft.geometry(),
  scale: 20,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});

print(meanDictionary)


var palette = ['FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718',
               '74A901', '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201',
               '004C00', '023B01', '012E01', '011D01', '011301'];

// Center the map
Map.setCenter(87.32,22.40, 6);

print(EVI);
 Map.addLayer(EVI,{min: -1, max: 1, palette: palette},'Sentinel-2 evi')
Export.image.toDrive({
  image:EVI,
  description: 'evi',
  scale: 30,
 region: ft,
  maxPixels:34089663741
  });
```

Comment: Please paste your code here. People will be more likely to help if the code is on site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stritching values in `Map.addLayer` are for a `float` band type (-1 to 1), and are not really stretching much. To use `float` values you should not change the band's type to unsigned integer 16 bits. This would do it:

```js
var EVI=evi//.multiply(100).uint16();
```

and the stretching values should be wider to represent the range of the output:

```js
Map.addLayer(EVI,{min: -5, max: 4, palette: palette},'Sentinel-2 evi');
```

you can play around moving `min` and `max`

And if you want/need to change band's type, you should not use an unsigned integer as it not holds negative values, and also change the stretch values to adapt to it. Code:

```js
var EVI = evi.multiply(10).toInt8();
Map.addLayer(EVI,{min: -50, max: 40, palette: palette},'Sentinel-2 evi');
// full stretch
// Map.addLayer(EVI,{min: -125, max: 125, palette: palette},'Sentinel-2 evi');
```

This is a good option for reducing the size of the output